# Matlab concatenation possible bug

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

I would like to concatenate two 3d arrays in a way that supports concatenation when the left hand side is empty.
I'd expect the following code to work, but Matlab (2012b, and 2013a) seems to insert an extra zero matrix at the beginning.

```
a=[]
a =
 []
K>> a(:,:,(end+1):(end+2))=ones(2,2,2)
a(:,:,1) =
     0     0
     0     0
a(:,:,2) =
     1     1
     1     1
a(:,:,3) =
     1     1
     1     1
```

Is this a bug? What's the proper way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you initialize `a`. Consider the following:

```
>> a = [];    % equivalent to zeros(0,0)
>> [m,n,p] = size(a)
m =
     0
n =
     0
p =
     1
```

This is explained in the documentation of the [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function:

> **`[d1,d2,d3,...,dn] = size(X)`**, for `n > 1`, returns the sizes of the
>   dimensions of the array `X` in the variables `d1,d2,d3,...,dn`, provided
>   the number of output arguments `n` equals `ndims(X)`. If `n` does not equal
>   `ndims(X)`, the following exceptions hold:
>
> - `n > ndims(X)`: size returns ones in the "extra" variables, that is, those corresponding to `ndims(X)+1` through `n`.

The size is used by [`end`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html#br1dtdk-1) to compute the index returned. To see this in action, we could overload the `end` function with our custom version:

#### @double\end.m

```
function ind = end(a, k, n)
    ind = builtin('end',a,k,n);
    keyboard
end
```

with the above function saved somewhere on the path, call:

```
>> a = [];
>> a(:,:,end+1) = ones(2);
```

You will see that the computed index `ind` returned by `end` is 1, which is then incremented by one `end+1` resulting in `a(:,:,2)=ones(2)` hence the extra space at the beginning is filled with zeros.

To fix this, initialize the matrix correctly:

```
>> a = zeros(0,0,0);
>> a(:,:,end+1) = ones(2);
```

Comment: ok so maybe the builtin `end` function doesn't actually call `size` itself, but I think somewhere in its internal implementation it depends on the convention that an array size is considered 1's beyond its number of dimensions. This fact is ultimately used to compute the index to be returned (by multiplying the sizes along the dimensions which, when `end` is used beyond the array bounds to automatically grow it, will be `1*1*..*1 = 1`); see the sample implementation shown in that last link I gave. Of course since the function is builtin, we can't know how it's actually implemented..