# Initialize a 3D matrix and add new data

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here the code that i have as example:

```
aaa = [];
bbb = [];
for ii = 1:10
    [aaa(:,:,end+1), bbb(:,end+1)] = myfunction();
end
```

The function `myfunction`:

```
function [aaa, bbb] = myfunction()
    aaa = rand(5,3);
    bbb = rand(5,1);
end
```

I know i could use `ii` for sending the output from the variables to `aaa` and `bbb` like `[aaa(:,:,ii), bbb(:,ii)] = myfunction()`. I'm just curious to know why for `aaa` i generate a 5x3x11 matrix (shouldn't it be 5x3x10?)?. For `bbb`, it correctly generates a 5x10 matrix. Hence, why the `end + 1` works for `bbb` and not `aaa`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. In order to have `end+1` work for the third dimension, `aaa` should be declared as follow:

```
aaa = zeros(0,0,0);
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057892/matlab-concatenation-possible-bug) for further explication on why this works.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this has to do with how MATLAB defines an empty matrix. If you do `size(aaa)`, MATLAB will return `0  0`, as you would expect. `size(bbb)` returns the same. However, if you explicitly try to find the size of the 3rd dimension using `size(aaa,3)`, MATLAB returns `1`. So it appears that MATLAB defines an empty matrix as having zero size in the first two dimensions, and a size of 1 in all the other dimensions.

What this means is that when you do `a(:,:,end+1)`, you're actually accessing `a(:,:,2)`, because the end of the 3rd dimension of `a` is 1, even when it is empty. You don't have this problem with `b`, because it is only two dimensional, and the end of the second dimension of an empty matrix is zero.

EDIT: As an aside, you should always pre-allocate your matrices if you're going to be assigning values to them in a loop (MATLAB will have complained about this, I believe). If you don't, the matrices have to be resized on every loop iteration, generally resulting in a slower execution time.

Comment: Very interesting. MATLAB has some unintuitive quirks with empty matrices.

Comment: So the solutios would be to have a condition for the first case?